# Cannot enable nVidia Quadro M1000M and its proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, video, intel

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell Precision 5510 laptop but looks like the graphics driver for its discrete nVidia Quadro M1000M is not installed/configured properly such that it can't playback a couple of 4K videos that I've downloaded at 60Hz. The built-in video player plays them more like 1 frame every 10 seconds or so.

`lspci` shows the following devices:

```
$ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191d (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
```

`ubuntu-drivers devices` shows the following output:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
[sudo] password for behrangsa: 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000013B1sv00001028sd000006E5bc03sc02i00
model    : GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M]
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-361 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== cpu-microcode.py ==
driver   : intel-microcode - distro non-free
```

I have also installed the nvidia-361 drivers:

[image: Additional Drivers]

However looks like its kernel module is not getting loaded:

```
$ ls -1 /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/kernel/drivers/
acpi
ata
atm
auxdisplay
base
bcma
block
bluetooth
char
clk
cpufreq
crypto
dca
dma
edac
extcon
firewire
firmware
fmc
fpga
gpio
gpu
hid
hsi
hv
hwmon
hwtracing
i2c
idle
iio
infiniband
input
iommu
ipack
isdn
leds
lightnvm
macintosh
mailbox
mcb
md
media
memstick
message
mfd
misc
mmc
mtd
net
nfc
ntb
nvdimm
nvme
nvmem
parport
pci
pcmcia
phy
pinctrl
platform
power
powercap
pps
ptp
pwm
rapidio
regulator
remoteproc
rtc
scsi
spi
spmi
ssb
staging
target
thermal
thunderbolt
uio
tty
usb
uwb
vfio
vhost
video
virtio
vme
w1
watchdog
xen
```

The videos I have downloaded are:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0wCC3aLXdOw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iNJdPyoqt8U

Is there anything else I need to do in order to enable the full potential of the nVidia graphics card? Also Skylake mobile Xeon CPUs have integrated GPUs that can play 4K video at 60Hz with no problem at all. However as mentioned earlier at the moment I cannot render 4K video flicker-free and it renders more like 0.1 frames per second.

Comment: have you tried running `$ nvidia-smi`? if you get a nicely formatted table with your device listed as being active it's working. I get roughly the same list of kernel drivers, with nothing that looks like "nvidia"

Comment: I have a similar issue (same laptop but not the 4k display) where I can't use the nvidia card because i get tearing whenever I use the nvidia card. I tried several drivers and re-installs and nothing fixed it. I have been battling dell support for almost a month now and they do admit they don't even think the hardware is suitable for ubuntu (regardless of them advertising it as a ubuntu laptop). If you have any more info, please update your question :)

Comment: Have they agreed to replace your laptop? If so could you please PM me the email thread?

Comment: I am still fighting. They said they are contacting ubuntu for some info. I am still waiting to hear back from them. However, given how they advertise this laptop as ubuntu laptop, you should have no issues just sending it back to them

Comment: You can forget about dell. They have the most ridiculous and embarissing customer service of all times. I now had 2 rounds of this. The best comment I can offer from them: We can replace the laptop with a different laptop of the same kind. When I said: So you want to replace my broken laptop with a different broken laptop, he stopped responding to me. In any case I am now fairly certain that I am seeing this problem with mine: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/775691/linux/vsync-issue-nvidia-prime-ux32vd-with-gt620-m-/7

Comment: Sounds like they love a class-action suit. I uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Windows so at least it works. Now in Windows I get BSoDs once every 4-5 hours of use. The culprit seems to be this:  https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/895902/geforce-drivers/blue-screen-dxgmms2-sys/21/. So I had to disable NVidia using [this tool](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/).

Comment: yeah, i am running intel-only as this is the only way to use this laptop. FWIW: XServer 1.19 is in the pipeline and that should resolve the vsync issue and make nvidia optimus tech useable with ubuntu